# Is there a way to define single space or more in math mode to be \,?

Tags: math-mode

I am learning LaTeX and I find one annoying thing.

I have to keep typing `\,` when in math mode to add that tiny space between different variables when I want one. This makes the LaTeX code harder to read and modify.

For example, I'd rather just write

```
 $a b c$
```

and have it come out as

```
 a b c
```

instead of

```
 abc
```

Now one has to write

```
 $a\,b\,c$
```

So a single space or more, is interpreted as `\,` when in math mode, so writing `$a    b c$` it will come out to be `a b c`. If the `\,` is present, then that is ok. So when writing

```
 $a\,  b c$
```

it will come out as

```
  a  b c
```

I do not see that this will cause a problem. If I do not want the `\,` then I will write `ab` and if I want the space, I'll write `a b` much easier, less things to type, and the LaTeX code becomes easier to read.

Is it possible to have some magic macro or renewcommand to do this?

**Update**

Ok, thanks for the advice. Will take it. I thought I needed to add space to make it look better.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$s(t)= A_c \cos(2 \pi  f_c t + \beta  m(t))$$ 

$$s(t)= A_c \cos(2 \pi  f_c t + \beta\,  m(t))$$ 
\end{document}
```

Here is the output
[image]

after looking more at it, I see that I really did not need the extra space between the \beta and the m.

Comment: Don't add `\,` between letters denoting single variable or constants that are multiplied. This is *never* done in good math typography.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking I needed an extra space. But I think you and David are both correct. It does look better without an extra space. I put an example above. So, this is good news. I was adding `\,` everywhere and was getting tired. Now I do not have to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sidebearings of the math italic font are designed such that this should not be necessary, they are designed such that `$abc$` has traditional spacing for a sequence of variables and `$\mathit{abc}$` is the markup that uses a text italic font with tighter spacing for a multi-letter identifier.

However something along these lines does what you ask

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
$abc$

$\mathit{abc}$

$a\,b\,c$

$a b c$



{\catcode`\ =13 \def {\,}$ a b c $}

\end{document}
```

But making spaces active is likely to be incompatible with many other constructs that are not expecting that.

Comment: It would be possible to make the space only mathematically active by assigning it globally mathcode 32768 and catcode 12 inside `\everymath` and `\everydisplay`. Something like `\mathcodè`\ ="8000` `{\catcodè \ =\active` `\gdef\defmathactivesp{\def {\mkern18mu}}` `\global\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\catcodè \ =12 \defmathactivesp}` `}`. Of course `$\hbox{ }$` would then be still a problem if the space was currently catcode active.