# Spaces between numbers or letters within math mode in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, horizontal

I have been looking in the and Latex companion, and I did not find what I want to make. I write transparencies in beamer for my lectures, and I have observe that the space between numbers or letters is too small in the big screen, making difficult to read them properly.
I have tried to modify the spaces following the answer in this answer in StackExchange: [Answer in Stack](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/is-there-a-way-to-define-single-space-or-more-in-math-mode-to-be), but failed and obtain a strange error lists on a *suppo-pdf.mkii* file that begins with: `Use of \@@mptopdf@@newabove doesn't match its definition. \@@mptopdf@@newabove`.
A minimal **non** working example of my achievement is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer} %Class presentation


\catcode`\ =13 \def {\,}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Here, I find error.}
\[ %Math mode...
a 2 = 2 + 3
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have seen that beamer package modifies heavily the categories codes, or so I understood. Is there any way to make the command to make larger horizontal space work?
As an example, here is the same equation tipped without and with spaces. Here Latex takes care of the spacing, leaving too few space for a presentation, in my opinion:
[image]

In the next picture, I add a `\;` space between letters:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: You are the first person to have this concern. I'd like to see some examples of this. Anyway, here is why this does not work. You are making a space into a macro. But `beamer` is build on top of `tikz/pgf` and the option names in tikz often use spaces in them, this includes most beamer options. So when you make space active all these options no longer work.

Comment: I have added two pictures of the different equations to the question. Anyhow, is there any way to use the macro "trick" in `beamer`?

Comment: @alfeliz I am afraid that the only way is to add these spaces manually. :(

Comment: I don't really see any need to add spaces in this example, other than defining `tag` probably to insert its own space.

Comment: @daleif I am happy to observe that you don't see the need. But the point is that in a big screen, or in any text, for what matters, `Latex` always puts too few spaces between letters or numbers in math mode. Usually is just a little problem, but on the big screen of a presentation looks horrible... and difficult to read.

Comment: Again provide examples. If this was a geneal problem more people would ask questions like this. No-one has. So I'm taking this as a personal preference. We have many lecturers that use beamer on a daily basis, and noone complains.

Comment: I never said that it is not a preference. But still, the point is that when a person looks at the screen, with the standard Latex separation, it is difficult to read. The struggling faces of my students can tell you that.

Comment: If you just want to globally adjust the spacing between notation in mathmode, wouldn't it be better to just redefine the various `muskips` which control how much spacing is inserted by default between various math atoms? See section 1.11 in [this document](https://www.tug.org/~hvoss/).

Comment: The problem is in the way that Latex handle math items: Letters and numbers have no space between them, so there is no space to modify...

Comment: For what it is worth, I just tried the alternative solutions posted on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/making-mathmode-obey-spaces). Both harald's and egreg's answers _compiles_ fine with beamer (as opposed to what you have which doesn't even build). But for neither is the extra spaces visible.