# How to use Haskell-like syntax in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'd like to have mathematical notation with Haskell-like function application, for example, `max a b / min a b` (division of the greater of a and b by the smaller of them), but it's improperly spaced:

[image: \( max a b / min a b \)]

How can I make that the `a` and `b` are more apart? I could add an explicit space, but I use such notation many times, so it would be very inconvenient and prone to inconsistencies, so I don't consider it an option. Is there a package for it? It would be nice that there would be a package fixing the spacing and providing macros for operators like `$` in Haskell (although the macros for operators are not a great problem; I could do them by myself).

I use LuaLaTeX, so things specific to it are available.

Comment: No tried it but https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TeX-my-math

Comment: You could set `\Umathordordspacing\displaystyle=\thinmuskip` and `\Umathordordspacing\textstyle=\thinmuskip` but that would also affect the spacing between letters in `\max` and `\min` so it's only halfway there.

Comment: Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94697/is-there-a-way-to-define-single-space-or-more-in-math-mode-to-be could be used but that could break other parts of the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is for typesetting LaTeX formulas in Haskell code; it's not for what I want.

Comment: @HenriMenke Where can I find documentation about `\Umathordordspacing`?

Comment: @matj1 It's in the LuaTeX manual: http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/luatex.pdf